# Get startup console logs in iOS WebView

Tags: ios, cordova, console.log

In a Cordova application, any calls to console.{log,warn,error,etc} before connecting Safari's developer tools do not appear in the console. This makes it impossible to debug startup errors. How do I get those messages?

Bonus question: How do I get the WebView to stop on debugger; lines prior to connecting with Safari?

Answer (score 3):

This simple trick can be useful, just open the console in Safari and run:

```
window.location.reload()
```

Answer (score 1):

I remember a friend telling me about a way to keep safari web inspector running regardless of whether or not the app is in the foreground or not.  [I found his article](http://jbavari.github.io/blog/2014/06/18/cordova-and-the-safari-web-inspector/) and here are the details -

**The first thing to do is to set a global hotkey – steps:**

- Open System Preferences / Keyboard
- On the right panel, select `Application Shortcuts`
- Add a hot key – use whatever keys you want (I used `CMD + ALT + I`)
- Have the matching key be `index.html` or whatever your cordova’s main
  html file is

**Steps to keep open SWI**

- Launch Cordova App
- Open SWI
- Close SWI
- Launch SWI with quick key as set up in global hotkey `Application Shortcuts`
- Close App
- Reopen app – notice SWI is still running and continues to give us logging/debugging!

Aside from the technique above have you installed this plugin below and inspected logs in Xcode?

`cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.console`

Do you use Ripple Emulator?  [Here is a great post on setting it up](http://www.raymondcamden.com/2013/11/5/Ripple-is-Reborn).

Comment: I can't get the Application Shortcut trick to work. When I close the app, the SWI window closes. I have tried closing by going to the home screen, closing via the app switcher, closing the simulator - any of these, as soon as the index.html frame leaves scope, the SWI windows closes.

Comment: After installing `org.apache.cordova.console`, I see no change in the Xcode output.

Comment: Does `ripple` do iOS? I only see docs for emulating android devices.

Comment: @DavidSouther After you install the `console` plugin, please try running `cordova prepare ios` and then `cordova build ios`.  Let me know if this fixes the issue with no console output in Xcode.

Comment: @DavidSouther Yes Ripple will allow you to emulate iOS devices, all original iPhone up to iPhone 5.

Answer (score 1):

There is a nice new tool, pretty straightforward, which solves your problem. Have a look at `GapDebug` [here](http://www.raymondcamden.com/2014/7/2/GapDebug-a-new-mobile-debugging-tool), it's pretty much new but works great for me!

It does exactly what you are trying to achieve with the Safari Remote Inspector, in particular it doesn't close the sessions when exiting the app and therefore catches all console output.

Also very interesting in combination with Android, because you get one tool for debugging both platforms accordingly.

Comment: GapDebug no longer works as of iOS 10, and there are no plans to continue development.

Answer (score 1):

I gave up and simply did the following:

```
// At beggining
window.logs = [];

// Just push the logs
window.logs.push(err)
window.logs.push(string)
```

Then you can inspect the logs in the developer console log screen by typing in, logs.

Answer (score 0):

I could of course override or wrap console.log to push log messages to an array, `window._log`.

```
(function(){
    var _console = window.console;
    window.console = {};
    window.$log = {};
    ['log', 'warn', 'error', 'debug'].forEach(function(level){
        window._log[level] = [];
        window.console[level] = function(){
            var args = Array.prototype.slice.apply(arguments);
            window._log[level].push(arguments);
            _console[level].apply(_console, arguments);
        }
    });
}());
```

Answer (score 0):

You just have to click on the round arrow here and restart your webapp!

[image: Web Inspector]